# Regular expression to match everything between first occurrences of two words, both of which appear more than once

Tags: regex

I want to parse this [json](http://api.mixcloud.com/alivefrommaryhill/semicast/embed-json/) and pull out everything that appears between the first occurrence of the word **feed** and the first instance of the word **widget_standard**.

I figure that this should be easy enough but my [regex](http://rubular.com/r/CVuR6azX3s) actually matches everything between the first occurrence of *feed* and the **second** occurrence of *widget_standard*.

What do I have to do to my regex `/(feed=http.*widget_standard)/i` to only match up to (and including) the end of the first occurrence of the word **widget_standard**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [lazy star](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) match `.*?` like this:

```
/(feed=http.*?widget_standard)/i
```